# How to show several tables with a single query

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to display several tables in which a particular element should only be listed using a single database query only. I am using the IF to condition the display of a particular element in order to separate the information. But I can not, I do not realize if syntax is incorrect or if it will be possible to do this.

```
<?php
    require_once('const.php');
    $conn = mysqli_connect(DBHOSTNAME,DBUSERNAME,DBPASSWORD,DBDATABASE) or exit('Error:'.mysqli_connect_error());
    mysqli_set_charset($conn,'utf8');
    $query = 'SELECT product.nome AS nome, category.name AS category, product.value
        FROM product INNER JOIN category ON product.category_id=category.id';
    $res = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or exit('Error:'.mysqli_error($conn));
    ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4"><p>Plates</p></th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        if(isset mysqli_query($query['category']) == ("Plates")){

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
            ?>
            
            <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['name']; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['value']; ?></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <?php
        }
    }
        mysqli_free_result($res);
        mysqli_close($conn);
        ?>
    </table>
```

Comment: This is not a question. PLease have another go. Also please explain what is happening in your `mysqli_query()` call, or at least what you think is happening

Comment: Seems like you want to add a `category.name = 'Plates'` to your WHERE clause in the query

Comment: What I desire is that, with the query, a single one, afterwards I would like to filter the exibition related, if it is possible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh I think I understand now. You want to query the database once but use portions of the result set in a number of places in your page.

So run the query and place the resultset into an array that you can use again and again if you wish to.

```
<?php
    require_once('const.php');
    $conn = mysqli_connect(DBHOSTNAME,DBUSERNAME,DBPASSWORD,DBDATABASE);
    mysqli_set_charset($conn,'utf8');

    $query = 'SELECT product.nome AS nome, category.name AS category, product.value
              FROM product 
                    INNER JOIN category ON product.category_id=category.id';

    $res = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
    $all_results = [];  // init the array
    while ( $row = $res->fetch_assoc() ) {
        $all_results[] = $row;
    }

    #some drives allow fetch_all() so you could replace above while loop with
    #$all_results = $res->fetch_all();   // get all the results one call

    ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4"><p>Plates</p></th>
        </tr>
    <?php
    // using the array, pick only the Plates category rows for this sction of the page
    foreach ( $all_results as $row ) {
        if ( $row['category']) == "Plates" ){

    ?>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['nome']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['value']; ?></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
    </table>
```